# How to drag screenshot after annotating?

Tags: preview, screen-capture, quicklook

Taking a screenshot and dragging its icon from the small icon in the corner directly into various applications or image uploads is very handy.

It's also very handy that I can open it right there and make some quick annotations.

But is there a way to drag the image directly from the quick window? I've tried combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Opt</kbd>/<kbd>fn</kbd> plus dragging, but it either draws a line or moves the window. Pressing done makes it go away and I have to go to the Desktop to retrieve it.

It's a small thing, but I do it so often that it's become obnoxious.

[image: quick image annotation modal]

Comment: I think you'll come up against the same obstacle as in Preview. The edit you see in front of you is an unsaved file, after hitting Done the changes are then applied back to a flat file on your desktop. You can't drag the unsaved file, as it would have to save as you drop it. It's just not designed to do that. It's very similar to this issue, though for completely different reasons - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/435784/85275

Comment: Not sure if drag & drop is available from that particular window but you can copy & paste the picture using keyboard shortcuts whenever applicable or convenient. First press Command+A to mark all of the picture and then Command+C to get it into the buffer and finally Command+V to paste it wherever you like if possible.

Comment: @Alper - that won't include the annotation, for the reasons mentioned above.